# Add hidden value to form field

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a value to my search form that is invisible for the users so that when they look for pizza they are actually searching for: #pizza#

I'm using wordpress and I use this code for the search form.

```
<li id="search-10" class="widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="margin-left:418px;">
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar">
    </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: Why don't you just put in the # server-side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work: **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/subhaze/zkSph/)**

JavaScript

```
function wrapSearch() {
    var text = document.getElementById('s');
    text.value = "#" +text.value+ "#";
}
```

HTML added `onsubmit="wrapSearch()"` to the form tag

```
<li id="search-10" class="widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/" onsubmit="wrapSearch()">
    <div>
        <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="margin-left:418px;">
        <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" >
    </div>
    </form>
</li>
```

Comment: How do I add that to my code? Sorry I should have pointed out I'm a noob at web design

Comment: I got it, it opens in a new tab though. Do you know how can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: yea.. sorry about that I updated the example about shortly after I submitted it to not have the "_blank". I used that in the fiddle so the URL would show. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
function searchValue(val)
{
if(val.value!='')
{
  val.value = "#"+val.value+"#";

return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
</script>   

<input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" onclick="return searchValue(document.getElementById('s'));">
```

Comment: Search is still working but it works the same as before. Maybe I placed your code incorrectly. I replaced the 4th line of my code with your code. Thanks

Comment: if(val.value!='')
{
alert(val.value);

Comment: I replaced the if(val.value!='') line with that one and it still doesn't work. But I'm not sure if that's what you meant. Was it correct to replace the 4th line with your code? Or where does it go?

Comment: <script>
function searchValue(val)
{
if(val.value!='')
{
  val.value = "#"+val.value+"#";

return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
</script>   



<li id="search-10" class="widget_search"><form role="search" method="post" id="searchform" action="http://chusmix.com/">
    <div>
    <input class="ubicacion" type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" style="margin-left:418px;">
   <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Buscar" onclick="return searchValue(document.getElementById('s'));">


    </div>
    </form>
</li>

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery

```
$('#source').change(function() { 
    $('#target').val("#"+$(this).val()+"#") 
});
```